# How to apply a function to each element of a list, in a specific column range?

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

Given a list of matrices with different number of columns:

```
set.seed(123)
a <- replicate(5, matrix(runif(25*30), ncol=25) , simplify=FALSE)
b <- replicate(5, matrix(runif(30*30), ncol=30) , simplify=FALSE)
list.of.matrices <- c(a,b)
```

How can I apply functional programming principles (i.e. using the [purrr](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/) package) to operate on a specific range of columns (i.e. 8th row, and from 2nd to the end of columns)?

```
map(list.of.matrices[8, 2:ncol(list.of.matrices)], mean)
```

The above returns:

```
Error in 2:ncol(list.of.matrices) : argument of length 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map_dbl` makes sure the returned values are numeric and double. `~` and `.` is a simplified way to specify the function to apply.

```
library(purrr)

map_dbl(list.of.matrices, ~mean(.[8, 2:ncol(.)]))
[1] 0.4377532 0.5118923 0.5082115 0.4749039 0.4608980 0.4108388 0.4832585 0.4394764 0.4975212 0.4580137
```

The base R equivalent is

```
sapply(list.of.matrices, function(x) mean(x[8, 2:ncol(x)]))
[1] 0.4377532 0.5118923 0.5082115 0.4749039 0.4608980 0.4108388 0.4832585 0.4394764 0.4975212 0.4580137
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution using the `Map` function in base-R:

```
Map(function(x){mean(x[8,2:ncol(x)])},list.of.matrices)

#[[1]]
#[1] 0.4377532

#[[2]]
#[1] 0.5118923

#[[3]]
#[1] 0.5082115

#[[4]]
#[1] 0.4749039

#[[5]]
#[1] 0.460898

#[[6]]
#[1] 0.4108388

#[[7]]
#[1] 0.4832585

#[[8]]
#[1] 0.4394764

#[[9]]
#[1] 0.4975212

#[[10]]
#[1] 0.4580137
```